# Find all the positive integers $m$ such that $p_{m}≥2m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Find all the positive integers $m$ such that $$p_{m}≥2m$$

where $(p_{m})$ is the sequence of prime numbers

I have no idea to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $7 < 2\cdot 4$, while $11 > 2\cdot 5$, and every prime after that is odd.

Answer (score 3):

We have $p_n\ge n\log(n)\ge 2n$ for all $n\ge 8$. This follows from the standard estimates, e.g., see [here](http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~ramare/TME-EMT/Articles/Art01.html).

Comment: Isn't the $\log \log n - c$ term important here?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I didn't notice the reference to Rosser 1938.

Answer (score 0):

@Dietrich Burde's answer does the hard part, of proving the high-$m$ behavior.

However, the correct answer to the problem is

$$
m \in \{1 \cup \{n | n \geq 5 \}$$

Comment: Isn't this the complement of the desired set?

Comment: No, the question is to find $m$ such that the $m$-th prime is at least as big as $2m$.  Not many of those...

Comment: Then your answer is wrong, e.g., for $m=2$ we have $p_2=3$, which is **not** at least as big as $2m=4$.

Comment: You are right.  I have to change the answer. $m=1$ still works(!)